# What is a simple way to log all items in a list using log4net (or other logging frameworks)?

Tags: .net, logging, log4net

I usually have methods returning IList.
I need to log the result coming back in this list.

Is there a better way than looping on the items inside the list and printing them one by one like this?

```
foreach(string productName in productsNames)
            {
                prodsNames.Append(productName + " ");
            }
Logger.Debug("Loading data for Producers: " + prodsNames);
```

is there some way of making this easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a wrapper for log4net that exposes a method like this:

```
void Debug(string message, IList elements);
```

The implementation could look be as follows (some details are omitted):

```
public Debug(string message, IList elements)
{
    // this.Logger returns a reference to ILog object
    if (this.Logger.IsDebugEnabled)
    {            
        string logMessage;
        // build the string that you want to write to the log
        this.Logger.Debug(logMessage);      
    }
}
```

That is just an example: You can design your interface the way that is best suited for you.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166438/what-would-a-log4net-wrapper-class-look-like) you can find some ideas what a wrapper might look like.

Comment: maybe also consider this, if you write a wrapper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049992/when-using-wrapper-how-to-preserve-class-and-method-name-for-log4net-to-log/3448439#3448439

Answer (score 1):

Serialize the list to **XML**, log the **XML** string.

Comment: Thanks, I've added serialized my list into json before I pass it to my dynamic object and then to serilog and it worked. It was just a basic string list I was hoping serilog would handle it but seems like it's not sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason to not to use `string.Join()`?

```
Logger.Debug("Loading data for Producers: " + string.Join(" ", productsNames));
```

Comment: This definitely works, but has the side effect of spending CPU cycles/heap allocations on the formatting, even if the debug logging level isn't enabled (whether this matters depends on the perf requirements of the situation, of course :-))

Answer (score 1):

With NLog and Serilog you can do this:

```
Logger.Debug("Loading data for Producers: {producers}", prodsNames);
```

See also https://messagetemplates.org/

Comment: Unlike the string-formatting options, this has the benefit of the elements being nicely searchable using queries like `producers[?] = 'apples'`, if you send the events to a JSON-capable log server.