# Best way to access to log4net wrapper App.config

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, log4net-configuration

As many people using **log4net** I have my own **log4net** **wrapper** that centralizes all the logging through different projects, also saves some repeated references to **log4net.dll** in each project.

I am using this solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166438/what-would-a-log4net-wrapper-class-look-like). Together with [this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0c5d7fbb-94a3-4221-ab91-9732c5acee58/cannot-resolve-dependency-to-assembly-because-it-has-not-been-preloaded?forum=clr) to avoid having to reference **log4net.dll** in projects where I use my wrapper.

I got it working for a simple console application, where I know where the App.config is located and its name:

```
FileInfo configFileInfo = new FileInfo("App.config");
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(configFileInfo);
```

I see potential problems here:

1. Each project can have its own App.config.
2. This file can change its name to {projectname}.config. (in release perhaps?)
3. App.config file properties have options like copy, embedded, etc. (but where exactly, can it get mixed up with other App.config?)

**In short:**

What is the best way to access in a comfortable way the wrapper App.config wherever it is being used?

Comment: Do you have a web app or an executable? Are these only one on multiple ?

Comment: The wrapper is a library for an application, no web technology is envolved. What you mean with multiple?

Answer (score 1):

You get the config file name from [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.configurationfile.aspx):

> The configuration file describes the search rules and configuration
>   data for the application domain. The host that creates the application
>   domain is responsible for supplying this data because the meaningful
>   values vary from situation to situation.
>
> For example, the configuration data for ASP.NET applications is stored
>   for each application, site, and computer, while the configuration data
>   for an executable is stored for each application, user, and computer.
>   Only the host knows the specifics of the configuration data for a
>   particular circumstance.

Comment: Hi @stuartd Thanks for the answer. Does it make sense for a library project to have its own app config? Would be cleaner if embedded?

Comment: Sounds like you should move your log4net config out of the app config into a standalone file then. You can embed the log4net config file in the project and use the overload of Configure that takes a stream, or you could just store it as a static string somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the executing file which gives you the name of the config file. Something like:

```
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
```

or

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

Comment: Is this the best way? It sounds to me like very tricky... finally maybe is better to break down all and include the log4net.dll

Answer (score 0):

There many ways to solve this issue, depending on the exact demands, in my case I created the log4net configuration programmatically like this:

```
var hierarchy = (Hierarchy)log4net.LogManager.GetRepository();

var patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline";
patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

var console = new ConsoleAppender();
console.Layout = patternLayout;

var roller = new RollingFileAppender();
roller.AppendToFile = true;
roller.File = Path.Combine(Logger.LogPath, "log.txt");
roller.Layout = patternLayout;
roller.MaxSizeRollBackups = 5;
roller.MaximumFileSize = "100MB";
roller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size;
roller.StaticLogFileName = true;
roller.ActivateOptions();

hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(console);
hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(roller);

MemoryAppender memory = new MemoryAppender();
memory.ActivateOptions();
hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(memory);

hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Debug;
hierarchy.Configured = true;
```

Another approach could be to embed it as suggested in one of the comments.

As my wrapper is a library, makes no sense to create a specific app.config for that wrapper-library so the configuration options can be set up into the final app.config file where the log4net wrapper is going to be used.